# Axios call fail in ionic react typescript

Tags: reactjs, ajax, typescript, ionic-framework, axios

I tried make a call to a web service with axios and AJAX. None of them worked. In axios I get an error request aborted and in AJAX I get an error too.
I specified headers for CORS, I specified the type of content which is xml.

```
let configAxios: object = {
    responseType: 'document', 
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    }
}

export function getFornecedores(){
    console.log("Dentro do getFornecedores");
    
    axios.get(config.web_service_url + "/TM_GetEnt?pEntTp=F", configAxios)
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Axios falhou" + err))
}

export function getFornecedores2(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: config.web_service_url + "/TM_GetEnt?pEntTp=F",
        // async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var xml_node = $('DocumentElement',data);
            var entnm: any = [];
            var entcd: any = [];
            xml_node.find('Tabela>ENTNM').each(function(){
                entnm.push($(this).text());
            });
            xml_node.find('Tabela>ENTCD').each(function(index){
                    // $(".fornecedor-select").append($("<option>").text(entnm[index]).val($(this).text()));
                entcd.push($(this).text());
            });
            return {entnm, entcd};
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log( "ERROR", arguments );
            alert("Erro");
        }
    });
}
```

These functions are called in a useEffect in the component when the DOM is first loaded. How can I  make the calls return a valid response?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is sent by the server, not the client. Maybe that causes the request to fail.

Comment: It was failling even before I put that header